# ADODB : if in sql clause

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm newer in VBA, I would like to know how to build the new colum conditionally :
I would like to create the column VENTE from the column cl.CD_EVT :

cl.CD_EVT (if cl.CD_EVT in ('COPVT','XCOPVT','3 COPVT','COCVT','XCOCVT','3 COCVT') then VENTE="OU", else VENTE="NON"),"

But I suppose that it's not right syntax for VBA.

My code is :

```
 RECSET2.Open " select dossier.NO_POLICE, ev1.D_EFFET, ev1.ID_FAMILLE_PORTEF, ev1.ID_PORTEFEUILLE, gr.LB_COURT_GR_EVT, pers1.S_PRENOM||' '||pers1.S_NOM as Collaborateur, proto.CD_PROTOCOLE, ev1.ID_FAMILLE_PORTEF,comm.L_COMMENT_DOSSIER," & _
" dossier.UI_CREATION, ev1.LP_STATUT_EVT, sum(ev3.MT_BRUT) as Ecart, ev1.MT_BRUT, cl.CD_EVT (case cl.CD_EVT when 'COPVT' then 'OUI' when 'XCOPVT' then 'OUI' when '3 COPVT' then 'OUI' when 'COCVT' then 'OUI' when 'XCOCVT' then 'OUI' when '3 COCVT' then OUI else 'NON') as VENTE," & _
" tiers2.CD_TIERS as Tmandataire, pers3.S_RAISONSOC as Mandataire,tiers1.CD_TIERS as Tdepositaire, pers2.S_RAISONSOC as Depositaire, ev1.IS_EVENEMENT from DB_DOSSIER dossier left join DB_EVENEMENT ev1 " & _
```

Thank you for the help !

Comment: `RECSET2.Open "..."` is VBA; everything inside that string literal is SQL - the problem is with the SQL, not the VBA.. consider assigning that string to a local variable (e.g. `Dim sql As String`, then `sql = " select dossier.NO_POLICE..."`) so you can do `Debug.Print sql` and get the actual SQL being sent to `RECSET2.Open`; then you can grab the concatenated `sql` string from the immediate/debug output (Ctrl+G), copy it, and run it directly in the database to get a meaningful error message and fix the query in a SQL editor rather than in a VBA string literal.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you ! My problem is that I'm working in SAS with proc SQL. So my code works in SAS, but I can't translate it in VBA, beacause there is sometimes slightly different syntax that I don't know.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I found this but it doesn't work : cl.CD_EVT (case cl.CD_EVT when 'COPVT' then 'OUI' when 'XCOPVT' then 'OUI' when '3 COPVT' then 'OUI' when 'COCVT' then 'OUI' when 'XCOCVT' then 'OUI' when '3 COCVT' then OUI else 'NON') as VENTE

Comment: You're missing an `END` token, try `cl.CD_EVT (case when cl.CD_EVT in ('COPVT','XCOPVT','3 COPVT','COCVT','XCOCVT','3 COCVT') then 'OUI' else 'NON' end) as VENTE`

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you, but I still have an error : ORA-00904 "CL"."CD_EVT" :invalid identifier :(

Comment: SQL delimits strings with single quotes; VBA delimits strings with double quotes.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Sorry, I didn't understand. I have this:  dossier.LP_ETAT_DOSS not in ('CLOSE','ANNUL','A30')  in my code VBA and it works.

Comment: It's not a double quotes

Comment: Looks like the `CL` alias isn't defined? Verify your `FROM` clause is defining all the aliases used in the `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon It is defined. I added the complet version of my code to my main message if you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly, below

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `CASE WHEN...THEN...END`; take your `if` condition and move it to a `WHEN` branch, like this:

```
,CASE WHEN cl.CD_EVT IN ('COPVT','XCOPVT','3 COPVT','COCVT','XCOCVT','3 COCVT') THEN 'OUI' 
      ELSE 'NON' 
 END AS VENTE
```

Make sure the quotes are consistently `'single quotes'`, too; you only need to use `"double quotes"` to delimit the VBA string literal.

---

The SQL would be much easier to debug if you concatenated it in a separate instruction than where you're sending it to the connection:

```
Dim sql As String
sql = "SELECT .... FROM .... INNER JOIN .... WHERE ...."

Debug.Print sql '<< print the actual concatenated query string, 
   'then you can copy to your favorite SQL client, debug it with an actual SQL editor, 
   'and then come back here and fix the string accordingly!

RECSET2.Open sql, ...
```

---

Editing/debugging SQL in a SQL editor is much easier than doing it in a VBA string literal:

```sql
SELECT
    dossier.NO_POLICE, 
    ev1.D_EFFET, 
    ev1.ID_FAMILLE_PORTEF, 
    ev1.ID_PORTEFEUILLE, 
    gr.LB_COURT_GR_EVT, 
    pers1.S_PRENOM||' '||pers1.S_NOM as Collaborateur, 
    proto.CD_PROTOCOLE, 
    ev1.ID_FAMILLE_PORTEF,
    comm.L_COMMENT_DOSSIER,
    dossier.UI_CREATION, 
    ev1.LP_STATUT_EVT, 
    sum(ev3.MT_BRUT) as Ecart, 
    ev1.MT_BRUT, 
-- this is where the problem is:
    cl.CD_EVT(case when cl.CD_EVT in ('COPVT','XCOPVT','3 COPVT','COCVT','XCOCVT','3 COCVT') then 'OUI' else 'NON' end) as VENTE,
    tiers2.CD_TIERS as Tmandataire, 
    pers3.S_RAISONSOC as Mandataire,
    tiers1.CD_TIERS as Tdepositaire, 
    pers2.S_RAISONSOC as Depositaire, 
    ev1.IS_EVENEMENT 
FROM DB_DOSSIER dossier 
left join DB_EVENEMENT ev1 on dossier.IS_DOSSIER = ev1.IS_DOSSIER  
left join DB_EVENEMENT ev2 on ev1.IS_EVENEMENT=ev2.IS_EVENEMENT_PERE 
left join DR_LIEN_EVT drevl on ev2.IS_EVENEMENT=drevl.IS_EVENEMENT 
left join DB_EVENEMENT ev3 on drevl.IS_EVT_LIE=ev3.IS_EVENEMENT
left join DP_CLASSE_EVT cl on ev1.IS_CLASSE_EVT=cl.IS_CLASSE_EVT
left join DP_GROUPE_EVT gr on cl.IS_GR_EVT=gr.IS_GR_EVT 
left join DB_COMMENT_DOSSIER comm on dossier.IS_DOSSIER=comm.IS_DOSSIER 
left join DR_COLLABORATEUR_PROTOCOLE collabproto on dossier.IS_PROTOCOLE=collabproto.IS_PROTOCOLE 
left join DB_COLLABORATEUR collab on collabproto.IS_COLLABORATEUR=collab.IS_COLLABORATEUR 
left join DB_PERSONNE pers1 on collab.IS_PERSONNE=pers1.IS_PERSONNE 
left join DB_PROTOCOLE proto on dossier.IS_PROTOCOLE=proto.IS_PROTOCOLE 
left join DB_PORTEFEUILLE portef1 on ev1.ID_FAMILLE_PORTEF=portef1.ID_FAMILLE_PORTEF and  ev1.ID_PORTEFEUILLE=portef1.ID_PORTEFEUILLE 
left join DB_TIERS tiers1 on tiers1.IS_TIERS=portef1.IS_TIERS_DEPOSITAIRE
left join DB_PERSONNE pers2 on tiers1.IS_PERSONNE=pers2.IS_PERSONNE 
left join DB_TIERS tiers2 on tiers2.IS_TIERS=portef1.IS_TIERS_GESTIONNAIRE 
left join DB_PERSONNE pers3 on tiers2.IS_PERSONNE=pers3.IS_PERSONNE 
WHERE
    dossier.CD_DOSSIER in ('COROP','COROC') 
    and dossier.LP_ETAT_DOSS not in ('CLOSE','ANNUL','A30') 
    and ev1.D_EFFET>=@date and ev1.IS_EVENEMENT_PERE is null 
GROUP BY
    dossier.NO_POLICE, 
    ev1.D_EFFET, 
    ev1.ID_FAMILLE_PORTEF, 
    ev1.ID_PORTEFEUILLE, 
    gr.LB_COURT_GR_EVT, 
    pers1.S_PRENOM, 
    pers1.S_NOM, 
    proto.CD_PROTOCOLE, 
    ev1.ID_FAMILLE_PORTEF,
    comm.L_COMMENT_DOSSIER,
    dossier.UI_CREATION, 
    ev1.LP_STATUT_EVT, 
    ev1.MT_BRUT,cl.CD_EVT, 
    tiers2.CD_TIERS, 
    pers3.S_RAISONSOC,
    tiers1.CD_TIERS, 
    pers2.S_RAISONSOC, 
    ev1.IS_EVENEMENT
```

Side note, that's a lot of `LEFT JOIN`; if any of them can be changed to `INNER JOIN`, consider doing it, it should improve query performance a bit.

So the problem is here:

```
    cl.CD_EVT(case when cl.CD_EVT in ('COPVT','XCOPVT','3 COPVT','COCVT','XCOCVT','3 COCVT') then 'OUI' else 'NON' end) as VENTE,
```

That should read:

```
    case when cl.CD_EVT in ('COPVT','XCOPVT','3 COPVT','COCVT','XCOCVT','3 COCVT') then 'OUI' else 'NON' end) as VENTE,
```

And then I expect the `GROUP BY` clause to be complaining about `cl.CD_EVT` being missing; make sure the `GROUP BY` clause includes all non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't understand the diffrence between   cl.CD_EVT(case when cl.CD_EVT in ('COPVT','XCOPVT','3 COPVT','COCVT','XCOCVT','3 COCVT') then 'OUI' else 'NON' end) as VENTE,

Comment: and   case when cl.CD_EVT in ('COPVT','XCOPVT','3 COPVT','COCVT','XCOCVT','3 COCVT') then 'OUI' else 'NON' end) as VENTE,

Comment: ev1.MT_BRUT, case when cl.CD_EVT in ('COPVT','XCOPVT','3 COPVT','COCVT','XCOCVT','3 COCVT') then 'OUI' else 'NON' end) as VENTE," & _

Comment: @Marie download and install SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) if you don't have it already, then connect to your database and edit your query in SSMS; you'll get clear error messages about any syntax errors, and then once you have a working query you can get it into a VBA string. Doing this in a VBA string literal isn't very far removed from madness! If at all possible, create a *view* on the server so that the SQL query lives on the server instead of a complex and hard-to-debug VBA string literal.

Comment: I found this solution :

Comment: Select Case RECSET2.Fields("VENTE").Value
     Case "COPVT"
     ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, Range("Colonne_12").Column).Value = "OUI"
     Case "XCOPVT"

Comment: @Marie "SELECT CASE" looks like Access-SQL. I was working with the assumption that the SQL dialect was SQL Server - please always tag a SQL question with the specific SQL dialect it involves :)

Comment: What do you think ?

Comment: Oups sorry I'm mostly worked in SAS, thank you, I'll note that

Comment: wait no, that's not Access-SQL it's actual VBA code. The SQL dialect is determined by the server you're connecting to. I don't know about SAS, but if the underlying database is SQL Server, then you need T-SQL (the SQL Server flavor of SQL); Access has its own SQL dialect, and other database engines have their own as well. Absent a very specific error message about what "doesn't work", it's going to be very hard to help further :)

Comment: I added the photo of my code to my main message just fyi. Thank you for help.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon's solution should work. Your Oracle error in comments under post is due to the missing comma *before* the `CASE` statement (which does not need to be wrapped in parentheses). Please make correction in SQL statement and only re-run the SQL statement without any other VBA code (i.e., `SELECT CASE`).

Answer (score 2):

To follow-up on @MathieuGuidon's correct answer, since you need to create a new column with `CASE`, situate the `CASE` statement in a comma-separated statement under `SELECT` clause. Your above attempt conflated the two columns with missing comma between original column (`cl.CD_EVT`) and calculated column (`VENTE`) and therefore raised the Oracle syntax error.

```sql
SELECT
   ...
   , cl.CD_EVT        -- RETURN TABLE COLUMN
   , CASE WHEN cl.CD_EVT IN ('COPVT','XCOPVT','3 COPVT','COCVT','XCOCVT','3 COCVT') 
          THEN 'OUI' 
          ELSE 'NON'
     END AS VENTE     -- RETURN CALCULATED COLUMN
   , ...
```

Additionally, for long SQL queries, consider saving all the text in an `.sql` file with all line break and space formatting for readability and maintainability. And to exercise parameterization, include needed qmark placeholders, `?`, (without quotes) for any values to be binded to query. Then, read the contents into VBA and using [ADO Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/command-object-ado?view=sql-server-ver15) object, run parameeterized query. In doing so, you entirely separate SQL and VBA.

**SQL** *(save as an .sql file with `?` placeholders)*

```sql
SELECT 
    ... -- WITH CORRECTED CASE STATEMENT SYNTAX FOR CALCULATED COLUMN
FROM ...

LEFT JOIN ...

WHERE
    dossier.CD_DOSSIER IN ('COROP','COROC') 
    AND dossier.LP_ETAT_DOSS NOT IN ('CLOSE','ANNUL','A30') 
    AND ev1.D_EFFET >= ?    -- QMARK PARAM PLACEHOLDER
    AND ev1.IS_EVENEMENT_PERE IS NULL

GROUP BY 
    ...
```

**VBA** *(read in .sql and run parameterized query)*

```vb
Sub RunSQLQuery()
    Dim cnn_Pegase As ADODB.Connection
    Dim RECSET2 As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim strSQL As String

    Set cnn_Pegase = New ADODB.Connection 
    cnn_Pegase.Open   '... ORACLE CONNECTION STRING

    ' READ .SQL INTO A STRING VARIABLE
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
          strSQL = .OpenTextFile("C:\Path\To\Script.sql", 1).readall
    End With

    ' RUN COMMAND
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
      .ActiveConnection = cnn_Pegase
      .CommandText = sql
      .CommandType = adCmdText

      ' BIND PARAM AND DEFINE TYPE
      .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("mydate", adDate, adParamInput, , Ma_date)
    End With

    ' OPEN RECORDSET USING COMMAND OBJECT AS SOURCE PARAMETER (NO CONNECTION)
    Set RECSET2 = New ADODB.Recordset 
    RECSET2.Open cmd, , adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic

    '... USE RECORDSET

    RECSET2.Close: cnn_Pegase.Close
    Set cmd = Nothing: Set RECSET2 = Nothing: Set cnn_Pegase = Nothing
End Sub
```